# Extract first span child with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to extract the first `span` with the text `Extract this text`. Already tried:

```
element.find_element_by_css_selector(".moreContent span:nth-child(1)").text.strip('"')
```

This is not working, I am not sure why. The output is just empty.

```
<p class="mainText">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  <span class="moreEllipses">…&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="moreContent">
    <span> Extract this text </span>
    <span class="link moreLink">Show More</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

However I am getting this, so Selenium finds the element but why the output is empty:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="e7012b303842651848aa0b0e40f5d5c1", element="df5644e9-fc98-4300-ad86-9ff433154d82")>
```

EDIT:

I managed to solve this by clicking on show more button. For some reason i can't extract the content if not visible even if present in page.

Comment: which element you are looking for? …&nbsp or Extract this text?

Comment: @ShubhamJain "Extract this text"

Comment: Does the Xpath I have witten below answer works?

Comment: @ShubhamJain, unfortunately not. Unable to locate element

Comment: Does this element inside any frame tag?

Comment: If the element is located successfully but text is empty I suspect there are other elements on the page meeting your selector. So the first element that meets one does not contain text.

Comment: try that ---   element.get_attribute('innerHTML')

Comment: @AlexeyR. there is only onle element with this class name: moreContent

Answer (score 0):

As per your cssSelector it seems you are targeting below

```
<span> Extract this text </span>
```

You can use below Xpath:

```
(//p[@class='mainText']//span[@class='moreContent']/span)[1]
```

OR

```
(//span[@class='moreContent']/span)[1]
```

Example Code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//p[@class='mainText']//span[@class='moreContent']/span)[1]").text
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text from the first `<span>` i.e. **Extract this text** you need to to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `text` property:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.mainText span.moreContent>span"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()` method:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@class='mainText']//span[@class='moreContent']/span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```